# Product Catalogue side pane loads the entire data while adding the line item?

Tags: sugarcrm, sugarbean

We have upgraded to sugar 8.0. In that, as a new feature, we have a product catalogue dashlet in the sidebar to add line item directly to quotes on the quote create view. Now if I click on the record in the product catalogue it loads the entire recordset to the quote line item. So it loads all the fields of that record that overwrites my default value that is set in the Quoted line item.

Whereas if I add the line item via the normal way(PFA) it is working fine.

[image]

while adding the line item I am setting the product status to `Draft` by default but whereas if I load it via the side panel then the status of the product catalogue gets overwritten in the quoted line item.

Thank You